# PCB Design STM32F407VG

Tags: pcb, stm32

I designed a PCB with STM32F407VG MCU .But I'm not sure if it's true.Is there anything I missed or wrong? This is my first PCB work.
[image].

Comment: That is not a picture of a PCB but a schematic. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Also, your previous question which was about crystal and caps already gave you a huge list of what is wrong and what to read to know how to design it. Effectively you could just copy a reference design and be done with it.

Comment: I will use this schematic on the PCB. It will be the MCU part of the board. But I don't know if this is enough to run the MCU.

Comment: That's why in your previous question you were given a direct link to MCU document that will tell you how to design with it, so after reading it you know what is enough to run the MCU.

Answer (score 3):

I think I remember you. Your design has definitely improved, but there are several things to fix.

1. Your Vdd inputs on MCU  - which line is coming to them, what is it called? Vout? But you have a ton of caps on the right, which are supposed to be on the same line (C12, C10). That pile of caps are basically caps that are supposed to sit on MCU's Vdd, one on near each Vdd pin. You need to name the traces consistently. Either all those caps belong to Vout, or all those caps and lines going into MCU Vdd must be on the line called "Vdd" (or other name; but it must be the same name).
2. You don't have a reset pin connected. NRST pin ("not reset" or "reset when 0"). You want that line pulled high via a pullup resistor. 10k is a standard value, but anything from 2k all the way to 100k will work. If you leave that pin floating, the voltage on it will jump all over the place and the MCU may spontaneously reset all the time. Even if it has a built-in pullup (I think some STM32 do, not sure), it's strongly recommended to explicitly set it with an external resistor. You may want to have this reset line exposed somewhere for manual reset (=trace goes out and away from mcu to some pin you can physically short to ground to reset; or connect a button to it that will short it when pressed causing MCU reset).
3. BOOT0 pin also needs to be set explicitly and exposed. If BOOT0 is pulled down, the MCU will run program from flash (where your program goes) upon start. If it's pulled high to Vdd, MCU will run from internal hard-coded  bootloader (a special program  in ROM - read only memory - that can write or edit flash content - like writing new software into MCU). You probably want a pulldown on this one, as you probably need to run from flash like everyone else, but with a pulldown you can also run a bootloader if you ever need it by connecting that line to Vdd (there will be tiny current through the pulldown when you do it, but nothing wrong with that). Bootloader is not something you need to worry about, the ST-Link programmer will take care of programming the device, you don't even have to know what bootloader is for that, but you should just be able to have access to it, thus don't connect it straight to GND (just like don't connect NRST straight to Vdd although it will work too - you still want to have a chance to change the value there if you ever need it)
4. How exactly do you want to program it? If you have ST-Link programmer, you need to expose SWD pins. What pins are SWD pins you can find in datasheet. They are two pins, one for clock and one for data. This is how you upload firmware to it.
5. There are Vcap pins, I don't exactly know what they do (forgive me my unwillingness to go through the datasheet). You should find their description in datasheet and see what exactly they are and whether you need to do something with them by default.
6. Check datasheet for VDDA pin. Do you need to supply it with 3.3V? You probably do. It's a supply for analog stuff and ADC. Usually it requires some filtering, but connecting it to VDD like another VDD pin will work too for now. Just check if you need to do it at all

So, recommendations given, you have some work to do, but you're making progress. Keep it up.

Comment: 1) not all caps belong to 3.3V supply, as that MCU uses internal regulator (Vcap). 2) your understanding of the reset pin operation is not correct - a pull up is not needed or even recommended but a cap is 4) it does not need SWD as FW upload via UART, USB and CAN are supported

Comment: @Justme the caps I'm referring to are strictly all Vdd (I specified their names). 2) I think STM32 documentation still recommends external pullup. A cap is a good idea tho, I agree. 3) Firmware can be uploaded even via I2C. The question is, how. Bootloader is necessary for that. That's why I said I assume ST-Link. Without knowing what the programmer is, impossible to say. Also, during development it would be a smart idea to have SWD exposed anyway, although those pins can of course be used for something. But this is most basic project, no need to overcomplicate things

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no two STM32 developers that would agree on everything. I mean, the thing is pretty complex and there are caveats within caveats haha

Comment: 2) pull-up was only recommended for noisy environments but that mention was removed years ago 3) No I2C firmware upload on this MCU - not with the factory system memory bootloader. Of course you can write any custom bootloader you want but that still needs to be programmed via factory bootloader or JTAG/SWD.

Comment: Come on, you're just not willing to accept that having SWD pins exposed is a good idea :D Especially since it's the OP's first project. What you said was also right, no argument, I just want to make it easy for novice (tbh if my first project involved stm32 I would have hanged myself)

Comment: No, adding SWD is very good idea indeed, it is irreplaceable tool for software developement - but it is just not the only interface for flashing firmware, and frankly, the list of what to fix or improve will just be endless since there is no specific question about the design but a rather generic one. The basics are easy to get right after reading the hardware getting started guide.